# secant method rungekutta schrodinger

Tags: python, numpy

So I am trying to use the Secant Method to find a ground state energy, however I have tried multiple ways so far and all of them are returning errors.
My code so far :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
###First importing the modules as always

Me = 9.1094*10**-31
hbar = 1.0546*10**-34
ec = 1.6022*10**-19
###Defining some constants we will need, electron mass, h bar and electron    charge

a = 5*10**-11    ###Halfwidth of the well
N = 1000
xsteps = (2*a)/1000
xpoints = np.arange(-a,a+xsteps,xsteps)   ###Array of calculation points inside the well
###using a+xsteps so that it ends at x=a, and not at x=a-step

def V(x):
    if abs(x)<a:
        V=0
    else:
        V=10**15
    return V     ###Can be modified to add other variables, for now should simply return V=0 for all steps

def s(r,x,E):      ###Where r is a vector comprised of phi and psi
    psi=r[0]
    phi=r[1]
    fpsi=phi      ###function of dpsi/dx
    fphi=((2*Me)/hbar**2)*(V(x)-E)*psi    ###function of dphi/dx
    return np.array([fpsi,fphi])
r=np.array([0,1])    ###Initial conditions

def RungeKuttaSchrod1(r,xpoints,E):
    psipoints = [] # getting empty arrays ready for the vector variables
    phipoints = []
    for x in xpoints:
        psipoints.append(r[0])
        phipoints.append(r[1])
        k1 = xsteps*s(r,x,E) 
        k2 = xsteps*s(r+0.5*k1, x+0.5*xsteps,E)
        k3 = xsteps*s(r+0.5*k2, x+0.5*xsteps,E)
        k4 = xsteps*s(r+k3, x+xsteps,E)
        r = r + (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)/6
    return np.array([psipoints, phipoints])
```

---

### That's all the original code before trying to find the E that would match the boundary conditions (psi=0 at x=-a and at x=a)

I have tried these 2 so far and have both failed:

```
err = 1       ###error variable set
tolerance = ec/1000
E1=25*ec
E2=50*ec    ###intial guesses for the energy

#Secant method for this set of equations
while err > tolerance: 
        E3 = E2 - RungeKuttaSchrod1(r,xpoints,E2)*(E2-E1)/(RungeKuttaSchrod1(r,xpoints,E2)-RungeKuttaSchrod1(r,xpoints,E1))
        print "current best guess of ground state energy", E3
        err = abs(E2-E1)
        E1 = E2 #resetting E1 and E2 for the next iteration
        E2 = E3
```

and also this:

```
def fphi2(x,psi,E):
    fphi2=((2*Me)/hbar**2)*(V(x)-E)*psi
    return fphi2

psi = 0 ###initial condition


err = 1.0  ###intialising error variable

#Secant method for this set of equations
while err > tolerance:
    for x in xpoints:
        E3 = E2 - RungeKuttaFphi(xpoints,psi,E2)*(E2-E1)/(RungeKuttaFphi(xpoints,psi,E2)-RungeKuttaFphi(xpoints,psi,E1))
        print "current best guess of ground state energy", E3
        err = abs(E2-E1)
        E1 = E2 #resetting E1 and E2 for the next iteration
        E2 = E3
```

Neither of these have worked, anybody have any ideas?

Comment: More info would be helpful.  Are you tied to Runge-Kutta or are you looking for alternative methods?  How exactly is the code failing?  Wrong answers or some kind of run time errors?  If errors, which ones specifically?

Comment: *"Neither of these have worked"* - in what sense have they not worked? Are you getting an error message or an incorrect result? If the result is incorrect, in what way is it incorrect? If you want help with debugging then at the very least you need to be explicit about what the actual problem is.